# Bash: improper function/usage of command basename

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting

What I want in the following command is to find particular files and move them to the other directories while appending ".log" to the destination filename.

`` find /src/dir/ -type f -mtime +3 -exec mv {} /dst/dir/`basename {}`.log \; ``

But it fails because the `basename` command enclosed in the backticks does not operate properly. `$(basename {})` has similar result too.

`mv: cannot move /src/dir/foo to /dst/dir//src/dir/foo.log: No such file or directory`

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the shell sees the `` `basename {}` `` or `$(basename {})` before it handles the arguments to find and processes them. Write a script that does what you want and run it with `-exec` instead.

```sh
find ... -exec myscript {} \;
```

where `myscript` is something like

```sh
#! /bin/sh
mv "$1" /dst/dir/$(basename "$1").log
```

You can invoke the shell for each file found, so the following is also possible:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(basename "$1").log"' -- {} \;
```

But test such a solution properly to be sure quoting and escaping works correctly.

Comment: Thanks @choroba for sharing. Since the line is a part of a script itself, I wonder if I could just simply add arguments to the -exec or totally in a single line to have the work done.

Comment: You can add arguments, but you can't use shell syntax on them - unless you try to write something like `-exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(basename "$1").log"' -- {} \;`